# Cancel pending send through SOAP api

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I'm looking for a way to cancel a pending send through the SOAP API in Marketing Cloud.   I can use the Soap API to get a list of Send objects (using the object 'Send') and I can see that the IDs here correspond to the Job IDs of pending sends (as well as cancelled sends and completed sends) in my SFMC account.  I can't work out how to ask SMFC to cancel the send though.  Sorry if I'm missing something really obvious here

Comment: There's example soap for this here:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's example soap for this here:
[here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/canceling_a_scheduled_send.htm)

To cancel a send it has to have a 'cancel' operation performed on it.  This is not included in the ruby sdk by default but it can be added by opening the class, adding the send object and defining a cancl method like this:

```
module FuelSDK

  class Send < Objects::Base

    include Objects::Soap::Read
    include Objects::Soap::CUD
    attr_accessor :folder_id

    def cancel
      perform_response = client.soap_perform id, 'cancel', properties
      if perform_response.status then
        @last_task_id = perform_response.results[0][:result][:task][:id]
      end
      perform_response
    end
   end
  end
```

This has the effect of reopening the class to add something in, adding send as an object you can do the usual API create/update/search things on and additionally defines a cancel method you can call on the send